# How to get quote id by customer ? Magento2

Tags: magento2

I use this way

```
$cartId = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getId();
```

but it works when the customer is logged in.
How can I get it and then when the customer hasn't logged in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain current quote for the customer (logged in or not) using session:

```
$this->session->getQuote()
```

where the `session` instance of `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` or `\Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote`

```
/**
 * @param Session $checkoutSession
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $backendQuoteSession
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
 * @throws LocalizedException
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $backendQuoteSession,
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
) {
    if ($state->getAreaCode() == \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML) {
        $this->session = $backendQuoteSession;
    } else {
        $this->session = $checkoutSession;
    }
}
```

In case you want to get a quote for the customer by customer id, you can use the `Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface::getForCustomer($customerId, array $sharedStoreIds = [])`.

Comment: Siarhey Uchukhlebau, it works fine, thank you very much

Comment: @RobinioTor I'm glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function __construct(
    ..........
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
    ..........
) {
    ..........
    $this->$cart = $cart;
    ..........
}
```

use below code in your function:

```
$quote = $this->getQuote();
// This will return the current quote
$quoteId = $quote->getId();
```

Comment: $this->getQuote() what is that?